# Is there a command to reload the sbt project while inside the sbt console of a project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I run `sbt console` within a scala project and can use all the code within the project in the REPL. If I make any code changes though, I need to exit the console (Ctrl + C) and run `sbt console` again to load the changes. Is there a way to simply reload code changes without exiting and starting up a new sbt console?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in sbt console you can't reload project, but you can exit repl printing `:q` but not exit sbt. After that you don't need exit from sbt you can enter `reload` command and sbt will reload project without exiting from sbt. But you need again type `console` for open REPL.
Another words, you can do followings:

```
sbt
console
*print some code in REPL*
*change sbt project*
:q
reload
*you will see sbt project changes does affect*
console
```

you will lost last REPL session objects and references but you will not load sbt project from scratch, reload is faster than another sbt starting.